# XC90 D5 Black smoke

Tags: diesel, volvo, smoke, xc90

I have a 163hp XC90 D5. I've noticed lots of black smoke under hard acceleration very similar to an issue 'Caius Jard' had;

"there's a periodic hesitation in the power delivery - again going up that hill in 3rd at about 2000 rpm, the power surges on and off slightly, every second or so. Generally the power delivery is poorer than it was, with the car sounding a little more "asthmatic/wheezy" than it used to"

Unfortunately, there's no solution posted for his issue.

Any thoughts please? EGR?

Comment: Have you checked for any codes?

Comment: What year is your Volvo?

Comment: Sounds to me like the cold side charge pipe has lost its integrity. Check to see if any of the piping from the turbo (cold side) up to the intake has come loose or has sprung a leak and is no longer containing boost.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. It's a 2005 163hp. I don't have a code checker unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black smoke usually means your engine is running "rich", i.e. burning too much fuel for the amount of air. There are many reasons this could be:

- Clogged air filter or blocked air supply
- Fault air flow sensors over-reading air flow
- Bad injectors delivering too much fuel
- Faulty injector pump or regulator delivering too much fuel
- EGR valve

The turbo could also be a problem, and would also impact power delivery.

I'd check the air filter first, if it's nasty then replace it and see how you go. Next check your OBD codes, chances are the computer will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I replaced the air filter about a month ago. I should point out that once the car gets to about 2300 revs it revs fine and the smoke clears.

Comment: That sounds like it could be turbo related to me @Bigwelshdave

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say vanes, but it is hard to say for sure @Bigwelshdave

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Today I managed to resolve my issue. For the benefit of anyone else who may have the same issue, I'll run through everything I tried before finally fixing it.

First I tried removing the EGR and cleaning it. This may have made a slight difference but if anything, it was negligible.

I then got hold of a fault code reader which gave the code P0244 which is related to the solenoid for the turbo/wastegate actuator. I removed and cleaned this. Again, no difference.

Then I changed the fuel filter.......no difference...

Finally, I changed the intercooler. Problem solved (at last). Car drives like new. Huge thanks must go to Chris Parker for his instructional video which gave me the confidence to attempt changing it myself. Link to video here:  https://youtu.be/OeOhqKWG_J8

Thanks also to everyone else who helped and I hope others will find this useful.

Dave